# RabbitMQ queues not getting deleted despite reinstalling Erlang and RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ version: 3.8.2 Erlang 22.2

Due to some issues, I had to reinstall RabbitMQ and Erlang on the server.

Despite reinstalling the applications, the queues from the previous instance still exist as well as new queues are being created(queue names given by Guid's, hence unique).

Is this normal behaviour?
How do I delete the older queues which have no consumers attached to them? I have ended up with 25,000 queues this way :|

Thank you

Comment: Can you see the old queues in the Admin console?

Comment: @FrankNielsen, yes they are all listed in the Queues tab of the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.
Apparently, there is a policy which can be set from the RabbitMQ Dashboard, to delete Inactive Queues.

The policy is ***expires*** and it can be set for queues and exchanges(though the policy seems to delete queues only).

This policy deletes all queues after the stipulated time of inactivity(no consumers subscribing to the queue)

Answer (score 0):

Dependend on your usage of the queues, there is an option `auto-delete` for deleting the queues.

Queue declare - From doc:

> **bit auto-delete**
>   If set, the queue is deleted when all consumers have finished using it. The last consumer can be cancelled either explicitly or because its channel is closed. If there was no consumer ever on the queue, it won't be deleted. Applications can explicitly delete auto-delete queues using the Delete method as normal.

Read more here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.auto-delete

Comment: Hey, thanks for your prompt response.

I tried declaring the AutoDelete property as true in C#
but can this auto-delete be set as a policy via the management console?

Comment: No, it is not part of the arguments you can add on creation on the management console - so only at runtime. But try explain you setup, and why you do it that way. Maybe it can be done in another way.

Comment: I am using RabbitMQ via Masstransit. I don't think I can directly access RabbitMQ's declare() method. I am however able to set the IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurators's AutoDelete property as true. Will that work?

Comment: The question you should think of is: Can your solution continue operating if masstransit shutdowns and all queues has `auto-delete`? Why are you using random names for the queue?